# Addhandler, button.click not firing using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, addhandler

I am experiencing a problem with buttons and AddHandler. It only works if I use AddHandler Button1.click, AddressOf... in Page_load, but if I create the button dynamically in one of the sub routines, the event doesn't fire.

For example,

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
    <contenttemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder id="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
     </contenttemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <contenttemplate>
        <asp:Label id="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </contenttemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Label1.Text = Date.Now
    ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(DropDownList1)
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Label2.Text = "Panel refreshed at " + Date.Now.ToString()
End Sub

Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim b As New Button
    b.Text = "Click"
    ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(b)
    AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Button1_Click
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(b)
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
End Sub
```

The dropdownlist works, but the button doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have to regenerate your dynamically created controls on every postback (at last in Page_Load, better in Page_Init). You have to set the ID of the controls accordingly because ASP.Net needs it to identify which control caused a Postback and to handle the appropriate events.

You could save the number of created buttons in ViewState and use this to regenerate them on Page_Load. Increase the number when you add a new button. Use this number also to make the Button's ID unique(append it to the ID) to ensure that its the same on every postback.

For further informations, have a look the [Page-Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) and [ViewState with dynamically added controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic4).

Edit: As Joel commented, if you only need one Button you can set it's ID statically, but you have to regenerate it on postback f.e. to handle its click-event.

Comment: +1 - In this case since there's no iteration to generate the dynamic control, the ID could be set statically.

Comment: Thx for your answers, but how do I keep track of the buttons (more than one, that was just a dummy example) I create?
I mean, I know that I need to use ViewState, but I cannot pass the button to be serialized and I don't know what IDs I should give them.
Another question, debugging the code, it looks like the code in DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged get executed after the Page_Load even in response to a SelectedIndexChanged event.

thx again

Comment: @user649904: as i've mentioned above, store the number of already created buttons in an int-ViewState-Variable(f.e. "ButtonCount") and increase it whenever you create a new. In page-init you have to recreate all buttons(from 1 to ButtonCount)and add them to your placeholder. Ensure that the ID contains the index of the Button(the ButtonCount when you was creating it), so they get the same ID on every postback.

Comment: Wow, you are quick! :)
I am dynamically creating an HtmlTable and I need to add the buttons in specific rows, whenever the info contained in the other cells of that row need to be amended. How can I do that?

Comment: @user649904: that sounds to me as if you should create another question from that or at least edit this question and provide more informations/sourcecode, because i won't(and can't) answer it here in the comments ;) I would suggest to create a new one with another subject.

Answer (score 1):

Just to aid anyone who has this problem and isn't quite sure how to implement. Here's a quick example. 
This example starts out by displaying a dropdownlist. When user selects something from the dropdown, another dropdownlist appears.
I typed this off the top of my head, so it MAY contain errors, but you get the idea =)

In the aspx file, add a placeholder:

And in your codebehind:
...

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    'Store control count in viewstate
    If Not IsPostBack Then ViewState("ControlCounter") = 1

    'Rebuild dynamic controls on every postback so when page's life cycle hits Page_Load, 
    'selected values in the viewstate (asp.net default behavior) can be loaded into the dropdowns
    Build_Dynamic_Controls()
End Sub

Protected Sub Build_Dynamic_Controls()

    'Clear placeholder
    myPlaceholder.Controls.Clear()

    'This is where the control counter stored in the viewstate comes into play
    For i as Integer = 0 To CInt(ViewState("ControlCounter") -1
        Dim ddlDynamic as New DropDownList With {
            .ID = "ddlDynamicDropdown" & i,
            .AutoPostBack = True
            }
        'This is the event that will be executed when the user changes a value on the form
        'and the postback occurs
        AddHandler ddlDynamic.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ddlDynamic_SelectedIndexChanged

        'Add control to the placeholder
        myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(ddl)         

        'Put some values into the dropdown
        ddlDynamic.Items.Add("Value1")
        ddlDynamic.Items.Add("Value2")
        ddlDynamic.Items.Add("Value3")

    Next i
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlDynamic_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'When a dropdown value is changed, a postback is triggered (autopostback=true)
    'The event is captured here and we add another dropdown.

    'First we up the control count:
    ViewState("ControlCounter") = CInt(ViewState("ControlCounter")) + 1

    'Now that the "total controls counter" is upped by one, 
    'Let's recreate the controls in the placeholder to include the new dropdown
    Build_Dynamic_Controls()
End Sub
```

...